# How to assess significant land cover changes using Chi-square test?

Tags: spatial-statistics, classification, landsat, land-cover, land-use

I have a series of land use maps at different times as a result of a classification process on Landsat images. I am mapping 3 different thematic classes : bare soils, vegetation and croplands.

I would like to answer the following question : "are land use change values significant ?" I believe chi-square test might help here.

How does the test work for my use case, and how should I run it ? Should i sample some pixels (if so, how much ?), or or work with the entire rasters ?

Comment: Are your maps classified independently  or are they the results of change detection analysis ?

Comment: Maybe F test would be better

Comment: @radouxju my maps are classified independently, using training areas delimited by visual interpretation (2017).